# Bootstraps Tabs, open previous/preceeding tab when closing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have currently the following code:

```
function registerCloseEvent() {
 $("#tabs").on("click", ".close", function() {
   var tabID = $(this).parents("a").attr("href");
   var uuid = $(this).parents("a").attr("data-id");
   $(tabID).remove();
   var tabFirst = $("#tabs a:first");
   tabFirst.tab("show");
   $(this).parents("li").remove();
 });
}
```

which is closing/removing the current active tab and opens/activated the very first tab.

I however want to open the preceding tab instead of the first one and tried everything but no luck on how to achieve this.

Any help would be welcome

Edit: HTML code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">
 <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><button class="close closeTab" type="button">×</button>Some Title</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><button class="close closeTab" type="button">×</button>Some Title</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab"><button class="close closeTab" type="button">×</button>Some Title</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab11" data-toggle="tab"><button class="close closeTab" type="button">×</button>Some Title</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"> </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"> </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8"> </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"> </div>
</div>
```

Note that the #tab hrefs are variable depending on how many tabs are opened.

Comment: please provide the html code as well

Comment: @KAD - added the html code